# Dúvida em renderização de array em React

Tags: javascript, react, api, render

Estou desenvolvendo uma página que receberá imagens através de uma API. Eu faço o request e pego o response da API, até aí tudo bem. A questão é que quando faço o tratamento da resposta e crio um array com as URL das imagens eu não consigo renderizar na página. Só renderiza a última imagem. Segue trecho do código para ajudar:

Aqui eu faço a requisição à API através do useEffect:

```
const [storeImages, setStoreImages] = useState([])

useEffect(() => { 
 const arr = []
 try {
  fetch(`${BASE_URL}`)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    for(let index in data.artObjects){       
      arr.push(data.artObjects[index].webImage.url)
    }     
    setStoreImages(arr)
  })
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
 }
}, [])
```

A página esta desenvolvida dessa forma:

```
return (
<>
  <h1>Galleria</h1>
  
  {
    storeImages.map((img, index) => {
      
      return (
        <main key={index}>
          <img  src={img} alt='' />
        </main>
      )
    })
  }
</>
)}
```

Estou travado nesse ponto. Não consigo fazer as imagens serem renderizadas, somente uma aparece. Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço desde já.

**UPDATE**:
Com o ajuste feito no estado `storeImages`as imagens foram renderizadas.

Comment: Qual é a estrutura de `storeImages` depois do pedido ser finalizado e o estado atualizado ? Cada posição tem um objeto com `.webImage.url` ? `images` é suposto ser um array para cada uma das imagens a mostrar com correspondencia ao `storeImages` ? Se é o caso porque não tem o estado a ser construido com um `map` direto ? Algo como `setImage(storeImages.map(img => img.webImage.url));`

Comment: @Isac, `storeImages` tem um array com 10 posições onde cada posição é um objeto. Uma das chaves desse objeto é `webImage` que possui como valor outro objeto, que possui a chave `url`. É o valor dessa última chave que possui o link da imagem.
A sua sugestão não funciona pois o retorno de `storeImages.map` é um array de objetos, que precisa ser iterado para que `webImage.url` possa ser acessado.

Comment: `storeImages` é um array de objetos, certo, mas no meu exemplo ao fazer `setImage(storeImages.map(img => img.webImage.url));` estou a mapear o array de objetos para um array de urls. Não é isso que o estado de `image` é suposto ter ? Se não é então houve algo que não ficou claro para mim no que os valores de estado tem e devem passar a ter. PS ter um estado como `image` no singular que tem um array não é boa ideia, e induz em erro

Comment: Me equivoquei quando disse que o retorno do response da API era um array. É um objeto com outros objeto dentro. Eu consigo percorrer com um loop `for in` e dentro deste um `forEach`. Consigo criar um array com 10 URL's em `setImages`, mas somente a última imagem é mostrada. Editei o código da pergunta, colocando para a página renderizar as imagens logo após o estado `storeImages` seja criado.

Comment: Mas se você faz `setImages([img.webImage.url])`, então fica apenas sempre uma só imagem, ou seja um array apenas com um elemento. Se eu percebi correto o que pretende é construir um array com base no objeto de objetos. Então para isso inicie um novo array antes do `for` faça push la para dentro no `for` e utilize esse para o novo estado. Ex: `const arr = []; for (... in ...){ arr.push(img.webImage.url);} setImages(arr);`

Answer (score 1):

Tente da seguinte forma, usando o [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) no `setStoreImages`

```
const [storeImages, setStoreImages] = useState([])

useEffect(() => { 
 const arr = []
 try {
  fetch(`${BASE_URL}`)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    for(let index in data.artObjects){       
      arr.push(data.artObjects[index].webImage.url)
    }     
    setStoreImages([...storeImages, arr])
  })
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
 }
}, [])
```

Comment: É uma possibilidade @Guilherme. Eu consegui resolver fazendo `setStoreImages(arr)`.